# Consuming Soap OTA_AirAvailRQ service from Sabre

Tags: sabre

I'm implementing a call to Sabre OTA_AirAvailRQ. After going thorugh the documentation i have the request but Sabre keep responding:

```
 <stl:ApplicationResults status="Unknown">
  <stl:Error type="Application" timeStamp="2017-07-04T11:55:36-05:00">
   <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
    <stl:Message>Sending request to the Host failed</stl:Message>
    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.CONNECTOR_ERROR</stl:ShortText>
   </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
  </stl:Error>
 </stl:ApplicationResults>
```

The sample is from Sabre Site.

Any idea what is wrong with the request ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="0">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">132654</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">56465</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>12340</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="sabreXML"></eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData></eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>Shared/IDL:IceSessXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns:OTA_AirAvailRQ Version="2.4.0">
            <ns:OriginDestinationInformation>
                <ns:FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="12-12">
                    <ns:DestinationLocation LocationCode="DFW"/>
                    <ns:OriginLocation LocationCode="HNL"/>
                </ns:FlightSegment>
            </ns:OriginDestinationInformation>
        </ns:OTA_AirAvailRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

The  part should not be used.

If you use regular SOAP, you should send the OTA_AirAvailRQ part inside the body element. If you use SOAP with attachment, then the payload should just be the OTA_AirAvailRQ content.

Comment: Check the new request string. We use reguar SOAP so i removed the payload node. But still receiving an error from Sabre. This time Unexpected request processing error. Also o used examples from Sabre site and also returns error. Payload node was added after a lof of unsuccesdful attempts.

Comment: I've used your request and get a successful request, can you share all that you do for that request? I think you are adding something extra or missing something.

Comment: I have added the Complete Request above.

Comment: You'll need to create a session with the SOAP service SessionCreateRQ. You are using a BinarySecurityToken that was obtained with REST's OAuth or SOAP's TokenCreateRQ, and these are meant for sessionless transactions, OTA_AirAvail will not work with that token.

Comment: Now i'm using a session token but i still get an error from the Server. Check my new request body i posted in the question body above.

Comment: This is Fixed the problem was the credential when calling SessionCreateRQ (the session token service). Some credentials do not allow to call low level services. If you get the ERR.SWS.HOST.CONNECTOR_ERROR error then check the credentials sent to the SessionCreateRQ services.

Comment: Great, always check the home page of the service, which says if it should use a session (SessionCreate), or sessionless (TokenCreate or REST Authentication).